# Saving Images as Filenames in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a product information sheet from a supplier that needs to get uploaded into an ecommerce platform. However, the spreadsheet contains actual images in the image column instead of filenames. I figured out how to extract the images from the file and they are in directory now. This would work if every file corresponded to a particular row in the spreadsheet, but they do not. Some rows have 1 image, some have 2 or 3.

What I need is to now convert the images in the spreadsheet into their filenames. That way I will be able to match the filename to the images when the spreadsheet is uploaded.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What code are you using to extract the images? If you are looping through objects you might be able to loop through a row at the same time and extract the names?

Comment: If you save the XLS file as a zip or HTML it puts the images in a folder. So I have all the images in a folder, but I still need each cell where the image was to be a filename so it can be uploaded properly.